# Using Git to manage multiple forks from master branch for multiple clients

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fork

I have a master repository that contains a site I've developed, and I want this master repository to contain the base, generic contents of the product I'm working on. This master repository will be used as a starting point for sites that will be used by multiple clients.  Each of these clients will obviously have different settings (such as database connections, and perhaps branding) but will also potentially encompass custom features in the future.

What I was thinking of doing was having the master repository, and then forking per clients from the master branch, and then doing any kind of customizations on those forks.  So it would look like:

```
Master 
   Company A  
   Company B  
   Company C
```

One of my main concerns is how to synch up changes?  I don't think that there would ever be changes in a client's fork that would affect the master, but there are changes to the master that would definitely effect the forks.  Is this going to be a huge nightmare?  Is this the best way to handle a situation like this?

Answer (score 6):

I would use [rebase](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html). This command rewinds your branch to the point it diverged from the master, then replays your changes on top of it. Say you have this (ascii art borrowed from man page):

```
      A---B---C company_a
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

Do this:

```
git checkout company_a
git rebase master
```

And you'll be left with this.

```
              A'--B'--C' company_a
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

All of it is done automatically. On the off chance that there's a conflict, git will pause the rebase and allow you to resolve it. Diff to find the conflicts, then

```
git add conflicting_file
git rebase --continue
```

Or chicken out with:

```
git rebase --abort
```

This is just a summary, it's all in the man page.

Comment: I think the major problem with rebase is that you can have inconsistent states in your history. Knowing that the common-code will evolve and that the custom-code will be updated accordingly, a rebase could easily put your commits into a state that the custom-code does not match the contracts/interfaces of the common-code.

Answer (score 2):

I've lived that and it's an incredible mess. What usually happens is that your workflow will eventually become: forget master and fork from the nearest client. It then quiclky become a nightmare.

I strongly recommend refactoring the code to split things in 2 separated git modules one "core" and one for (each) company-specific code. Without any idea on the exact nature of you repo, it's difficult to say. I've seen both at work and split modules is MUCH more manageable then a bunch of customer branches in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option here would be to use submodules. Create a repository for each of the customers that will contain the per-customer stuff, and add the common core repository as a submodule of each. It might take some rearranging of subdirectories, etc., but that would allow you to do development of the common core and upgrade each customer on their own schedule. One downside is that it eats up a little more disk space for all the extra submodule copies - this can be partially mitigated by using `git`s shared object store features, though, and disk space is pretty cheap anyways.

You could probably accomplish what you want within a single repository with a branch-per-customer approach, but keeping all the branches straight and making sure you don't accidentally cross-merge or something, would require caution.

Comment: Using a submodule with common code also requires that you explicitly updates the submodule of each customer. With the disadvantage that when using submodules you cannot cherry pick (choose which changes you want to incorporate), unless you also branch the submodule - which would be the worst of both worlds. Keeping client-branches would also allow you to upgrade each customer on their own schedule. With the added advantage that you are not restricted to the subdirectory problem.

Answer (score 1):

What I have tried and it works is to have a repository for your product code
e.g `product_x`. You fork it for each of the clients resulting separate repositories like that:

`product_x_company_a`,
`product_x_company_b`,
`product_x_company_c`,

Since pull requests are not allowed from parent to child but allowed only from child to parent we have to follow a different route.

What I do locally, is I add in each company repository e.g `product_x_company_a` 
except for `origin` that has its own repo url, also `parent` pointing to `product_x` repo

`git remote add parent https://github.com/ourcompany/product_x.git`

If you type `git remote -v` you will see a list like that in this specific folder:

```
origin  https://auser@github.com/ourcompany/product_x_company_a.git (fetch)
origin  https://auser@github.com/ourcompany/product_x_company_a.git (push)
parent  https://auser@github.com/ourcompany/product_x.git (fetch)
parent  https://auser@github.com/ourcompany/product_x.git (push)
```

Then changes being pushed to the product can be pulled from children repos locally like that:

`git pull parent master`

and if everything works as expected locally - they can be pushed to specific clients repo like that:

`git push origin master`

You don't usually need to commit something as you are passing commits from one repo to the other basically!

You are allowed to have company specific code changes in those repositories and at the same time if there is a bug or feature developed in the product (parent) it can be pushed to all clients with minimal effort :)

Note that it is better to be done not directly on `master` but on a `dev` branch, so you can run your unit-tests, integration-tests, code quality metrics and manual tests first before it goes in the production branch.

Answer (score 0):

Source control is a good way to handle this.  When you merge/rebase Master into A, and lines 10-20 have been changed in Master, and lines 15-25 have been changed in A, then post-merge:

```
lines 10-15 will match what's in Master
lines 15-20 will be marked as in-conflict, and you'll have to resolve the differences manually, use your favorite tool like diffmerge
lines 20-25 will match what's in A
```

I'll guess that the customizations will be in fluff content areas, whereas most of your Master changes will be nuts-and-bolts functionality.  In such a case, it's possible that your project won't see frequent conflicts.  So manually reconciling the conflicts in lines 15-20 can get to be a pain in a large project, but it is still probably the best way to handle your situation.

Comment: So would I fork the master, and then rebase whenever I need to do an update from the master to the child?

Comment: Yes. In git speak, a fork is called a branch.